# How does control reach the end of this non-void function?

Tags: c

```
int test_ex(int num) {
  
  if (num >= 1000) {
    printf("+");
  } else {
    return num;
  }
  
}

int main(void) {  
   test_ex(123812);
}
```

I'm confused here as est_ex returns an int, but both if/else clauses return ints, right? So how would it be possible for there to be a non-int return here, I've been stuck on this for a long time. I tried adding a redundant return 0 but that messes up the output I want.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you starting from the premise that this code is correct? You shouldn't as it is not. *both if/else clauses return ints, right*? Not it's not right. There's only one return statement. All the other paths have no explicit return and is thus Undefined Behaviour..

Comment: What does your function return if it enters the `if` branch?

Comment: printf returns an int representing the number of characters right? So that's what it should be.

Comment: I don't see any `return` statement in your `if` branch. So no, there's nothing telling the compiler it should be returning the result of `printf`

Comment: *So how would it be possible for there to be a non-int return here*. What does that mean? Do you have code you are not showing that is used to reach that conclusion? The code shown does not even use the return value of the function so it seems that it's irrelevant in that context what the value is.

Comment: @MaretRipple: If that's what you want, then you should have `return printf("+");` there.

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake now. I falsely assumed printf returns a value by itself. Adding the return right before fixed it, thank you!

Comment: And then you don't even need the `else` clause, just a naked `return num;` would do.

Comment: `printf` does return a value, but your code ignores it.  You could be explicit and do `int r = printf(...); return r;` if you don't want to write `return printf(...)`.  There's no implicit return of the last statement executed in C.

Answer (score 2):

If the function "reaches" the end brace it returns.  If it is supposed to return a value, then the behavior is undefined.

Update: it is undefined behavior only if the return value of the function is used:

from C99 6.9.1 Function deﬁnitions:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Since the snippet of code in the example doesn't use the return value, there is no undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that you do not return any int if num >= 1000 so,

```
int test_ex(int num) {
  // No matter you should return
  if (num >= 1000) {
    printf("+");
    return num;
  } else {
    return num;
  }

}
```